# removeAllDeliveredNotifications doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

RemoveAllDeliveredNotifications doesn't remove notification when from the settings notification type is banner.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter * center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
```

Comment: Can you explain your scenario in more detail?